# <table> inside a <div> inside a <div>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a Navigation Bar at the top of a webpage, which I have done by creating a `<div>`. Inside that I have another `<div>` for where I want to put my Navigation Buttons. Inside the Navigation Buttons `<div>`, I have a table with some text that are supposed to be buttons. I've made a border for all the `<div>`s and I've made a border around the Table.

My problem is this: every time I try to position the Navigation Button's `<div>` inside the Navigation Bar `<div>` with Absolute positioning, the Navigation Button's `<div>` jumps outside the border of the Navigation Bar `<div>`. Then the Navigation Bar `<div>` becomes a very small line at the top of the page.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="NavBar">
    <div id="BtnBar">
        <table cellpadding="10" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Test #1</td>
                <td>Test #2</td>
                <td>Test #3</td>
                <td>Test #4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then for my CSS I have...

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}

#NavBar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 1200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#BtnBar{
    position: absolute;
    left: 454px;
}
table{
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Here's what it outputs as...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5KGF.jpg

Comment: how you want that to be???

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to use a table to hold the buttons?

Comment: Well I'm a really huge noob, so Im using the <table> to equally space the buttons.

Comment: From an accessibility standpoint tables should be restricted to presenting tabular data (see http://webaim.org/techniques/tables/ ). There are a number of other semantically correct solutions for presenting navigation menus that would allow for equal spacin.

Comment: Thanks to all of you I've fixed it! And I'll make sure to remember that tip about the No-Table-Navigation Bars!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have set both Nav and Button bar as Absolute then you need to explictly specify the height, otherwise the container will collapse, eg.

```
#NavBar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

A better solution would be to make the BtnBar relative so that the NavBar resizes itself for whatever its contents size is

Comment: I did do relative to try it out, but then the div border moved out of the NavBar Div. And thanks for the good answer btw. Can you tell me why that happens when I change it to relative?

Comment: It happens because position:absolute means that you need to specify the position of an element (eg. height, width, top, bottom) no matter what is inside, whereas relative means the element will fit into the page flow (eg. it will position itself depending on its content and neighbors)...hope that makes sense ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Setting something to position absolute takes it outside of the normal flow of of the document. You should only use position absolute on the outermost div.

More problematic in my opinion is that you are using a table for layout. That's a very bad practice.

Try something like this instead:

HTML:

```
<div class="NavBar">
    <ul class="BtnBar">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.NavBar { width: 1200px; border: 2px solid black; margin: auto;}
.BtnBar { display: table; margin: auto;}
.BtnBar li { display: table-cell;  padding: 10px; }
```

Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zwop5o6L/

Comment: Not a big fan of ma'am, but it's better than sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, i feel your problem stems from having the btn bar div absolute. This css doesn't collapse any parent containers and center's your buttons. One of the only good things about a table is it's vertical and horizontal centring behaviours LOL. Make the table width whatever you want and your buttons will stretch and stay centered.

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}

#NavBar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 1200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#BtnBar{

}
table{
    margin: 10px;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could avoid complications by using padding to postion the nav bar, you could also create your buttons using css and pad the left handside of the buttons to replicate a table this will make the website more accessible